# Emacs moves curly braces -- how to stop

Tags: c++

I have the "bsd" style selected for C++ programming but when I go to define a function and enter the curly braces on the new line this happens:

[image]
[image] Press RET
[image]

Is there any way to stop this behaviour so that I end up with this instead:

[image]

**Update 1**

I looked in the messages buffer after typing some curly brackets and found the following two messages:

```
LSP :: Applying 3 edits to `test.cpp' ...
Applying 3 edits to `test.cpp' ...done
```

Therefore I suspect that lsp-mode is to blame for this issue. There is little in the Emacs graphical configuration to do with this and I don't know whether the lsp-mode files would be written in C++ or Elisp; can anyone point me in the direction of the relevant files so that they may be changed?

Comment: I should note that I followed the instructions on this website https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/tutorials/CPP-guide/ to make C++ programming easier. I'm assuming this has changed my configuration in a way I don't want

Comment: I have looked in the messages buffer and there are couple of messages saying

LSP :: Applying 3 edits to 'test.cpp' ...
Applying 3 edits to 'test.cpp' ...done

This leads me to suspect that, in order to fix it, the lsp-mode configuration or code needs to change.